# python CGI print function

Tags: python, cgi

I have a very stupid problem, i'm trying to print the type of a variable direct to the browser, but the browser skips this action, here an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb;  cgitb.enable()


def print_keyword_args(**kwargs):

    # kwargs is a dict of the keyword args passed to the function
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        a =     type(value)
        print "<br>"        
        print "%s = %s" % (key, value), "<br>"
        print "going to print<br>"
        print "printing %s" % a, "<br>"
        print "printed<br>" 
        print "<br>"    

form = {'a': 1, "v": None, "f": "ll"}

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>form</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print_keyword_args(**form)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

The browser response is:

```
a = 1 
going to print
printing 
printed


v = None 
going to print
printing 
printed


f = ll 
going to print
printing 
printed
```

Desired response is:

```
a = 1 
going to print 
printing "int"
printed


v = None 
going to print 
printing "boolean"
printed


f = ll 
going to print
printing  "str"
printed
```

source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>locoooo</title>
</head>
<body>
hola
<br>
a = 1 <br>
going to print<br>
printing <type 'int'> <br>
printed<br>
<br>
<br>
v = None <br>
going to print<br>
printing <type 'NoneType'> <br>
printed<br>
<br>
<br>
f = ll <br>
going to print<br>
printing <type 'str'> <br>
printed<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is in <> of type output, a way to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION:

```
cgi.escape("printing %s" % a, "<br>")
```

Comment: How does the browser "skip the action" exactly? If you look at the source of the page, what do you see?

Comment: Thanks for your coment, very instructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser doesn't show the `<type 'int'>` brackets as it thinks it's an HTML element:

```
In [1]: a = type(1)

In [2]: print a
<type 'int'>

In [3]: print "printing %s" % a
printing <type 'int'>
```

You can either view the source of your page where you should see the output or you need to escape the `<` and `>` brackets, for example like this:

```
In [4]: import cgi

In [5]: print cgi.escape("printing %s" % a)
printing &lt;type 'int'&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially printing the type object:`a = type(value)`, which will print `<type 'int'>`. The browser will process it as a tag. To get your expected output try using the following:

```
a = type(value).__name__
```

The type object has an attribute called `__name__` which can stores the string value of the type. Example:

```
>>> # Expected output
>>> type(1).__name__
>>> 'int'
>>> # Unexpected output
>>> type(1)
>>> <type 'int'>
```